# Vue-js reactive element affects a different element

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

We have a vue-js page (@vue/cli 4.5.6) with numerous components, which mostly works fine. One component is doing something I don't understand: There are two radio boxes, one at the top of the page, one at the bottom. They seem to be completely unrelated; here's one

```
    <template v-for="qSection in qSections">
    ...
      <!--- loop to output individual questions here --->
      <tr v-for = "question in qSection.questions">
        <td>
          {{ question.txt }}
          <div v-if="question.incf">
            <br/>
            <textarea rows="2" cols = "80" :name= "question.cmt" 
              v-model="question.cmt" placeholder = "Comments here"
              class="hideOnPrint"
            />

            <div class="print-only"> {{ question.cmt }} </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <!-- okay, three more tds to hold radio box-->
        <template v-for="icnt in [1,2,3]">
        <td>
            <label v-if="question.otherAns" class="other-ans-label">
              {{ question.otherAns[icnt].txt }}
            </label><br/><br/>
            <input type = "radio" :name= "question.quesn" :value = "(icnt%3)"
              v-model="question.answer"/>
        </td>
        </template>
      </tr>
```

Here's the other

```
        <template v-if="section.otype1 != 'Laboratory'">
          <div class="hideOnPrint">
            <input type = "radio" :name = "section.accept" :value="1"
              v-model="section.accept"
            >
              {{acceptPhrase}}
            </input>
            <br/><br/>
            
            <input type = "radio" :name = "section.accept" :value="0"
              v-model="section.accept"
            >
              Investigation is incomplete. See comments.
            </input><br/><br/>
          </div>
        </template>
```

So what has been happening is that clicking the radio button in the bottom area (only for value="1") *un*-clicks the radio button in the top area (question.answer, whichever is chosen).
According to the Vue app in Developer Tools, the top area data is still set: questions.answer = 2 still, say. And indeed if I set it equal to 1 there and back to 2, that radio box gets re-checked correctly.

How is this happening and what do I change to fix it? Or what should I do to diagnose it. Thanks!

I'd like to put up a working example but not sure how; the rest of the page has a lot of parts.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, wow: I realized my mistake. It's those lines in the code,
:name= "question.quesn"
and
:name = "section.accept".
These are setting the name of the radio box to the value of those fields. They both end up equal to 1, and therefore the two radio boxes become a single radio box. Clicking one turns the other one off.
Shouldn't be using name at all; v-model does the job.